# How to model medical cloth wrapping?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, workflow, bezier-curves

I am modeling a gun and from a concept that I found on the web. The gun has little strips of cloth around its handle. I'm not sure what the best way to model them is. As you can see, the straps are overlapping each other, bending, curving, and folding.

[image]

How can I model this? I would rather not use a cloth simulation.

It's suppose to be high poly model

Comment: Do you want them to be high or low poly? Fast answer from me could be: extrude two vertices to get overall look of those stripes, solidify, apply, sculpt, retopologize, bake normals and done.

Comment: Seems he want high poly since my low poly version was downvoted 3 times and upvoted 2 times. Seems people here prefer high poly versions unless OP ask explicitly for lowpoly.

Comment: @DarioOO I actually used your method to create a high poly model, I used multiresolution modifier and sculpting to make it look better.

Comment: Mee too. I used it several times, still get downvoted by someone :D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[image: example of meshing a striped handgun]

This is just to get the average shape, you can of course make a even simple shape if you need a lowpoly model. However once you got the basic shape set up (possibly try to use Edge Loops to help you) you can try to sculpt more details aound each ring by adding even more edge loops to add every single bend in every stripe. In theory you don't need to model each single bend since you can achieve that with pretty good texturing.

To get a realistic work get some piece of wood with a shape similiar to your hand gun, really wrap it with stripes, and take a photo and work on that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it:

step 1: get a plane parallel to what you want to wrap.

step 2: extrude the plane around the object

step 3: Add a solidify modifier

step 4: Add a loop that runs across all the faces and pull it inwards using Alt+s

step 5: Add extra support loops

step 6: Set every face to smooth shading and add a subdivision surface modifier

[image]